# jQuery/JavaScript: is the garbage collector clearing my variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, garbage-collection

I've seen a number of similar questions, but no one seems to answer my problem.

```
var mainDataObject = null; // Global

// Called when DOM is ready with $(function() { ... })
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: '...',
    success: function(json) {
        mainDataObject = json;
    }
});
```

Will *mainDataObject*, or its contents, be cleared after some time? Does this depend on the browser? Mind you, I need that variable to last for the entire lifetime of the page.

The problem I'm seeing is that, randomly, it appears that `mainDataObject` is emptied. I'm not able to reproduce the problem as it happens to random users using a variety of browsers and operating systems.

Comment: whats the scope of the ajax call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends in which context `mainDataObject` is created.

If it's a function(-context), the variable is cleared from the garbage collector when the function ends.

If it's within the global(-context) it will remain until you explicitly set it to `null` or the page is unloaded.

If of course, you create a closure somehow, somewhere, the function which closes over the context which creates `mainDataObject` copies the `Activation object` into it's `[[Scope]]` and the memory wouldn't seem to get cleared.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I added more info - mainDataObject is global.

Comment: mainDataObject is declared as global (above $.ajax) in this example

Comment: that is not true. When there is a closure inside the function, the variable will stay as long the closure function is referenced somewhere.

Comment: @Dario: if it's declared in the global object, it should contain it's value as long as your page lives. You would need to explicitly clear (null) its value.

Comment: @BiAiB: I guess I covered that.

Answer (score 0):

any javascript variable will last as long you can refer to it.

What you have to worry about is when variables are not garbage collected, not the contrary.